# How do I use jest outside of a test environment

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking

I'm hoping to leverage `jest.mock()` in a non-test situation. I want to [change the functionality of an external module](https://jestjs.io/docs/25.x/mock-functions#mocking-partials). In test code, I'm already using `jest.mock()` to stub out one function of the module so that it simply returns `true` always; now I want to do exactly the same thing from a standalone web application.

I don't know how to get the magic jest object in my app code like I get in my test code, so I've added `import { jest } from "@jest/globals";`. This makes `jest.mock()` available and it looks good in my IDE. Unfortunately, when I run my app, it spews out

```
throw new Error(
      ^
Error: Do not import `@jest/globals` outside of the Jest test environment
```

How do I get around this? I'm happy to do any of:

- bypass the check and just "make it work";
- have my application actually be a test or somehow host a Jest test environment; or
- use a different tool that does allow module faking in non-test environments.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76519309/edit) the question to include a [mre] of the problematic code and desired output.

Comment: A minimal reproducible example is already in the question :) A .ts file with just `import { jest } from "@jest/globals";` in it will produce the problem.

Comment: This seems likely to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What's the context here? You don't need Jest's whole mocking sandbox just to isolate your code from a third-party module - introduce a _facade_ so that you can easily control what's exposed to the rest of the system (including wrapping and changing that behaviour/interface to your specific needs).

Comment: why do you want to mock it ? You can simply replace it: `myObject.methodToMock = () => true`

Comment: I want some 3rd party code to be able to use a 4th party module which has a single function replaced by my function. I can't update either the 3rd or 4th party code. But if there's a JS/TS alternative to using Jest, that'd be awesome. I just don't know what that is or how to search for it.

Comment: From what I'm reading, `import` bindings are immutable. I don't know how Jest does what it does, but there doesn't seem to be any other way to change one module so that subsequent imports of it provide my custom implementation. And since I can't change the code that's importing this module that I want to change, it looks like the only option is Jest's mocking, or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I have working, but which I'm not particularly happy with, is:

1. Update jest.config.js (or whatever Jest config you're using) to define *index.ts* as a test file.
2. Wrap the important contents of the index.ts file in a `describe()` block.

This is a nasty workaround, and I'm not going to accept this answer :)